# File path issue

Tags: c#, file-io, xamarin

```
var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllText ("\\\\hds321\\Common Pay Sal\\Mobile App\\Android\\abc.pdf");
```

The above line errors out as :

Could not find file "/\hds321\Common Pay Sal\Mobile App\Android\abc.pdf".

Tried using a single \ instead of including the escape \. Still the same issue.

The file exists in the shared path specified.

Any resolutions please?

Comment: Yes, but I have the same error when I place the file on the desktop too. It errors out with a /<pathname> doesn't exist.

Comment: Where does the "/" come from?

Comment: That's my problem..  I cannot understand why a / is prefixed to the error. And that seems to cause the issue in the first place

Comment: The issue is specific to my Xamarin Android application. the same piece of code works fine when placed in a WinForm application

Comment: Are you sure an Android device can read files from network shared folders like a PC does? I highly doubt!

Comment: `/` would be the root folder in your android device. Maybe you need rood SD Card folder `Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory`? `Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory, "hds321/Common Pay Sal/Mobile App/Android/abc.pdf");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Xamarin utility assumes the path being accessed in on an SD card. Network paths cannot be used while developing code. Wish the error was clearer

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Path.Combine(), instead of trying to concat path names manually. Path.Combine() will take care of the nuances of your platform for you.

Answer (score -2):

id suggest using the @ infront of fixed path

```
var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllText (@"\\\\hds321\\Common Pay Sal\\Mobil App\\Android\\abc.pdf");
```

Seems like your accessing from a server ? if so then is the folder shared on the server 
if its a directory withing your application i would suggest using

```
var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllText (Application.StartupPath +@"\\hds321\\Common Pay Sal\\Mobile App\\Android\\abc.pdf");
```

this will limit errors on lower .net's hope this helps

Comment: Application.Startup is Winform specific and prefixing @ did not resolve the issue

Comment: Sorry @Max i didnt see the xamarin tag

Comment: Using a `@` means that you will have to halve your `\\` s. It's not going to make any real difference.